# How to use inversion of control to create plug and play code in java?

Tags: java, design-patterns, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, software-design

I want to create a Java SDK for my team which creates the ability for them to create say a simple Java Class ( a plugin of sorts), register it somewhere and have Java choose, during run time which java class plugin to use.

Let's take a trivial example: I have 3 Java classes. Inside each is a function that takes a string and prints out "Short Greeting" + inputStr, "Long Greeting" + inputStr, and "Blah" + inputStr) respectively. Say they all implement an interface.

I wanted a design where these classes would be **registered** somewhere and tomorrow someone else can write a 4th class which would print something else out (also implements same interface). The decision for which class to choose should be based on say a input from a user?

ie. I can say java -jar my.jar -inputString "John" -pluginName="long"

and the jar would instantiate the correct class and implement the correct logic.

I know that I can have a simple switch case statement or if else if and else logic but this was a trivial case and in reality I want my code to be modularized so future additions of plugins are completely separate from each other.

I was told to look into IOC and dependency injection but I didn't find any good tutorials online. Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance

---

Right so perhaps a trivial example was not in order. What I am designing is an SDK for determining which data store to call. I have other developers designing adapters for say calling a(n):

CouchBase (CouchBaseReterival.java)

REST service (ServiceRetreival.java)

HBASE instance (HBASERetreival.java)

All these adapters are implementing an interface (InformationRetreival.java) which has a method getInformation().

This SDK would be invoked by a REST call itself from a microservice. So a client call would contain say param x, y, z, and "cb" for couchBase. The microservice would call informationRetrieval.getInformation(x,y,z,"cb"). The code should inject in the correct adapter and execute the logic to return the correct response.

A Switch-Case / if-else logic is not so much complicated (perhaps I should not have used that word) as it is not a good design pattern when there are multiple adapters being developed and tested independently. (A requirement is loose coupling of code) I do not want to modify the logic of the code everytime a new adapter is added. Reflection is an option but again it requires a code change. I was looking for advice more along the lines of leveraging Spring's or PicoContainer's Dependency Injection suggestions/tutorials.

Comment: if the implementations are provided by other artifacts, JAVA service loader will solve your problem.but if you have multiple implementations available at run-time,when the service are loaded correct implementation should be picked and should be registered somewhere else to use it in the application.

Comment: Right that's where I was a bit confused where should I register these classes which contain their own implementation. Should it be a Configurator or a Container where I can then get them by name?

Comment: first look for examples how to use java.utill.ServiceLoader  . then when we load those services, we can picked the right implementation based on provided configuration and assigned to to field of  a Singleton class (ex: ServiceRegistry), then later in the application you can refer ServiceRegistry.getInstance().getMyService() to retrieve the implementation.

Comment: @hunter thanks that seems to be what I want and its native java which is even better but quick question the only requirement is that I have a txt file in META-INF/service/InterfaceName containing on each line the AdapterName for each adapter implementing the interface correct?

Comment: Yes, full qualified class names for each implementations.

Comment: I can tell you that with hk2 (http://hk2.java.net) we do plug-and-play easily (it was designed to be a DI framework that supports plug and play).  It is even able to do plug-and-play in a running system (no need to reboot the JVM) in many cases because it is totally dynamic even at runtime.  This extra flexibility makes it less like many other DI systems you will see (like CDI) but does support a lot of dynamic use cases like yours.

Answer (score 1):

In your concrete example, you would be more looking towards "Open/closed principle" for starters:

```
interface Greeter {
   public String getGreetingFor(String name);
}

abstract class BaseGreeter implements Greeter {
   public final String getGreetingFor(String name) {
     return getPrefix() + " : " + name;
   }
   protected abstract String getPrefix();
}

class ShortGreeter extends BaseGreeter {
   @Override
   public String getPrefix() { return "Short greeting"; }
```

The idea here: you do **not** want that each and any Greeter implementation has its own implementation. Instead, you put in another abstraction that is open for change (you can add other greeters) but that is closed for modification (the greeting function itself can't be overridden by subclasses any more).

[ obviously: if all implementations of your interface are really different, then this pattern doesn't work - but at least in your example that is not the case ]

For your second part - the default way of doing that is to use [reflection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/): as that allows you to instantiate arbitrary classes solely on **strings** at runtime; like:

```
String pluginClassNameFromUser = "whatever.package.SomeClass";
Class<Greeter> someClassInstance = (Greeter) Class.forName(pluginClassNameFromUser);
```

**But**: it sounds like ifs/switches already feel "complicated" to you; so that implies to me, that *reflection* is way beyond your current skills.

So, the easier alternative would really be something like:

```
public Greeter fetchGreeterFromUserInput(String userInput) {
  switch userInput.trim().toLowerCase(): {
    case "short": return new ShortGreeter();
    case "long" : ...
```

I hope this gives you some inspiration how to tackle your project.

Finally: if you are looking for an extensive (although advanced example) for doing a "real" design, have a look into "Agile practices" by Robert Martin (you can find the C# version of that book for free on the internet; and even when you dont know C#, that is a good starting point).